# How to fix "Server-Side Request Forgery" Fortify Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, fortify

Getting "server side request forgery" issue in Fortify report when using spring restTemplate.

I am making a call using restTemplate to some other REST service and I get the url as a parameter but it gives me this error

[image]

I hope I don't have this vulnerability in fortify

Comment: Do not use images for text (code, errors, logs, etc)

Comment: Add the actual message from the report to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Without the exact details on the finding of Fortify its hard to judge, but since you stated:

> I get the url as a parameter but it gives me this error

If the parameter `resourceUri` is user-defined and provided by a request, then this is a valid finding and your application is vulnerable to Server Side Request Forgery.

It would be something different if the URL is read from a configuration that cannot be influenced by users.